# Symfony2 assests in bundles directory 404 error

Tags: symfony, bundle, assets

After doing some research, I still cannot understand why my assets in the bundles folder return 404 errors when I try to reach them.

I can see the files on the server, but when I try to reach them, symfony returns a 404 error.

For example, I have this file on the server : web/bundles/aluser/images/li-plus.png, but trying to access it with https://my-site.com/bundles/aluser/images/li-plus.png returns a 404 error. But on the other hand I can access files in https://my-site.com/images/li-plus.png for example.

I did the assets install and dump commands, cleared the cache but no results.

Thank you.

Comment: What webserver are you using? If its nginx im betting you are missing the ```location / { try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers,

they pointed me in the right direction (a problem with the server) : 
I did a asset install and dump commands with the root user of the server, all files created were then associated to this root user, and apache wouldn't serve them anymore.

After a chown, everything was working again.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are on a local install it probably has to do with your server not pointing to the web folder. I had that problem on a shared hosting what i did was to make a symlink from server home (www, public_html or whatever) to web and it worked like a charm.